# php & ruby scripts accessing the same db and table can cause corruption?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby, concurrency

i have a php file which regularly writes and reads tables from mysql DB.

i have another ruby file that runs at the same time which reads and write to the same tables in mysql DB.

can there be potential issues with this set up ?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't care if it's PHP or Ruby. **Yes**, there are potential issues with *multiple clients accessing the database simultaneously*, though. There's *a lot* possible to go wrong.

Just one random example:

Client 1 intends to a) subtract 10 from integer column_x (= 10), and then b) add this 10 to integer column_y.

Imagine Client 1 is done with step a), but before it manages to do b), Client 2 comes, intending to do something only if either column_x or column_y value is positive. And erroneously does nothing, as far as the 10 has not arrived to column_y yet.

Basically, you're getting all the problems of [multiple execution threads with a shared state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Race_conditions.2C_mutual_exclusion.2C_synchronization.2C_and_parallel_slowdown).

To address such issues, [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) exist. MySQL provides several [transaction isolations levels](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html), which depend on the storage engine of your tables.

Thus, all the modifications (and reads for `REPEATABLE READ` & `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level) must be executed within a database transaction, starting with `START TRANSACTION`, and ending with `COMMIT` SQL statement. If there's a problem in the middle of your routine, and you can't finish the transaction as a whole, execute `ROLLBACK` to undo all the changes made since the `START TRANSACTION` call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL you can use:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT @A:=SUM(salary) FROM table1 WHERE type=1;
UPDATE table2 SET summary=@A WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

for more you can refer to: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-transactions.htm

Answer (score -1):

Yes. There are. You should be using transactions to ensure, that only one instance is accessing data, and that if there is an error, you can roll back.

Also it depend on what storage engine you are using.